# Убрать экспонент в Python

Tags: python

Как на Python убрать экспонент из `1.23e-06` и получить `0.00000123`?

Comment: Вроде как это одно и тоже число

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
print(x)
# 1.23e-06

print('{:0.9f}'.format(x))
# 0.000001230
```

Comment: ```format(1.23e-06, '.8f')``` разве не проще?

Comment: можно и так, но `'...'.format()` мне как то привычнее

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что речь идет о строковой переменной, в которой число записано в экспоненциальной форме? Если да, то так:

```
num = '1.23e-06'
print("{:.10f}".format(float(num)))
```

Получим:

```
0.0000012300
```

Обратите внимание размер дробной части перед `f` в форматированном выводе - если он у вас меньше необходимого, вы потеряете в точности.

Если это важно, то нужно использовать следующий формат:

```
import re
parts = re.search(r'\.(\d+)e.(\d+)',num)
res=len(parts.group(1))
exp = int(parts.group(2))+res
print("{:.{exp}f}".format(float(num), exp=exp))
```

Получим

```
0.00000123
```